# How to return mount point usage(df -h) in excel format in linux scripting

Tags: scripting

I want to display the output of Linux command `df -h` in excel format.
I tried by giving the output file extension as `.xls` but it returns the whole value in single field.

Comment: This doesn't have got to do with U&L.

Comment: is there any format to convert an output to excel in scripting

Comment: Excel format is a compressed XML file, i.e a binary format. How do you envision displaying that? As octal/hex dump? It would be interesting to understand why you display a binary format, it is rather hard to interpret that kind of compressed data.

Answer (score 3):

You could copy the output to a .csv file then import that into excel. This should give you a comma delimited csv file:

```
# df -h | sed -e "s/Mounted on/Mounted_on/g" | awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="," > df.csv

# cat df.csv
Filesystem,Size,Used,Avail,Use%,Mounted_on
8.5G,1.1G,6.9G,14%,/
tmpfs,495M,0,495M,0%,/dev/shm
/dev/sda1,485M,31M,429M,7%,/boot
```

Though this will have problems if you have anything mounted via LVM, as that will just be a filepath on a separate line. Not quite sure how you'd go about putting that in to excel anyway.

Comment: This also wouldn't catch filesystems with spaces in the name (such as NFS shares).

Comment: The LVM thing can be resolved by just adding `-P` to your `df` though.

Comment: [Example](https://dpaste.de/KFsA) output. It appears that `/proc/mounts` uses an escape code so it might make sense to iterate over the mount points there and just run `df -hP` on each one, sed'ing out the full mount point. and using the iterated version instead

Answer (score 1):

1. This is not exactly a U&L question.
2. Simply renaming a file doesn't magically change it's contents.

However, the following worked for me with LibreOffice and should do with Excel, too, though I can't tell you the exact names of the UI elements there. Also all fields containing spaces in the text (e. g. the headline) will break the column layout; see the other answers for possible solutions.

1. Export the output to a file with the extension `.csv`:
   `$ df -h > df.csv`
2. Open Excel (or Calc).
3. Import the file as type CSV (Comma-separated values)

   - Select spaces as field separators.
   - Mark the option to merge multiple field seperators.

If this doesn't work with Excel directly, use LibreOffice Calc and save it as Excel document.